# C# construction objects with builder

Tags: c#, design-patterns, constructor, builder, fluent-interface

[**Fluent builder**](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2010/04/14/a-fluent-builder-in-c/) is a well-known pattern to build objects with many properties:

```
Team team = teamBuilder.CreateTeam("Chelsea")
    .WithNickName("The blues")
    .WithShirtColor(Color.Blue)
    .FromTown("London")
    .PlayingAt("Stamford Bridge");
```

However, using it doesn't seem very clear to me due to one particular reason:

- Every `Team` object has its **minimal operational state**, in other words, set of properties which have to be set *(mandatory),* so that the object is ready to use.

Now, how should the `Fluent builder` approach be used considering that you have to maintain this state?

Should the `With_XYZ` members modify the part of the object, that can't affect this state?

**Maybe there are some general rules for this situation?**

---

### Update:

If the `CreateTeam` method should take the mandatory properties as arguments, what happens next?

- What happens if I (for example) omit the `WithNickName` call?
- Does this mean that the nickname should be defaulted to some `DefaultNickname`?
- Does this mean that the example (see the link) is bad, because the object can be left in invalid state?
- *And, well, I suspect that in this case the fluent building approach actually loses it's "beauty", doesn't it?*

Comment: Is Nickname, mandatory?  If so, it should be a parameter in the CreateTeam(string nickname) method.  Then the WithNickname() is an optional call that you might use to modify the the team once it's created.

Comment: fluent methods are always for optional parameters, not mandatory ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CreateTeam()` should have the mandatory the properties as parameters.

```
Team CreateTeam(string name, Color shirtColor, string Town)
{
}
```

Comment: So, the rule of thumb is that I should avoid leaving the object in the inconsistent state?

Comment: Yes - once it's constructed, it should be valid.

Comment: I'd say this answer misses the point of Fluent interface[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: @radarbob how is this missing the point? As far as I can see the wikipedia link you provided doesn't contradict the above.

Comment: @David - I was just taking the purist view of zero parameters in the creation method. I see the point of ensuring *mandatory* arguments for a minimal object creation

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me the points of Fluent Interface are:

- Minimize the number of parameters to zero in a constructor while still dynamically initializing certain properties upon creation.
- Makes the property/ parameter-value association very clear - in a large parameter list, what value is for what? Can't tell without digging further.
- The coding style of the instantiation is very clean, readable, and *editable*. Adding or deleting property settings with this formatting style is less error prone. I.E. delete an entire line, rather than edit in the middle of a long parameter list; not to mention editing the wrong parameter